# How to view Mamp Pro on a Mac OS X 10.6 from a PC over a LAN

Tags: macos, localhost, mamp

I've been trying to test my sites on IE on my PC sitting next to my Mac over the LAN.

I have Mamp Pro set up with port: 80 Mysql: 3306 with a virtual file with: 127.0.0.1 mysite.dev

On my Windows machine's hosts file I have my Mac's ip address with my virtual site next to it. But I can't seem to see it. On the PC when I type in the Mac's IP address I can see what files are in the folder but it doesn't actually display the webpage just the code.

I have tried turning off the Mac's firewall and also allowing Mamp and Mamp Pro in the firewall for incoming connections.

Is it possible to get this setup without doing porting forwarding and using DynDns?

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80

MAMP_Port_iteration_begin_MAMP
Listen MAMP_Port_MAMP - It's port 80 in Mamp Pro
MAMP_Port_iteration_end_MAMP
```

I've also tried to append ":8888" to the end of the url!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've already gone through the [MAMP setup guide](http://sawmac.com/mamp/).

Quick troubleshooting checks:

1. Do you see any pages being served up from the Mac itself? It'd be good to rule out any problems with your MAMP installation. Ideally, you'd see either the MAMP welcome page or your web site's index page.
2. Assuming that step #1 checks out, what do you see when accessing http:///? It'd be good to know what gets served up or if an error message is shown.

Note: Appending :8888 shouldn't work unless you've configured port forwarding or MAMP to use that port.

Comment: Yes I have completed that set up and Mamp Pro works as is on my local machine. In answer to your question all my virtual hosts show up on my Mac when I visit their respective dev domains mywebsite.dev On the PC next to my Mac the error message I receive is that it can't find the page. No port forwarding has been setup on my Belkin router.